# Bluetooth - is rfcomm totally bypassable as a protocol?

Tags: networking, protocol

I ask my question on programmers because:

- no coding is really involved
- this question is very conceptual concerning an exchange protocol.

#### Bit of context:

When you implement Bluetooth, like I do, you have to choose between multiple protocols, such as L2CAP and RFCOMM.

RFCOMM relies on L2CAP protocol.

#### Question:

Are there devices/applications out there that can be RFCOMM only (and only this, not supporting L2CAP exchanges)?

Comment: RFCOMM is build on top of L2CAP, how can there be RFCOMM without L2CAP?

Comment: This is exactly the point of my question: is it possible to restrict an app on that subset or not? I will not implement RFCOMM because I have very good l2cap implementation already. Will I have issues with my bluetooth experience if I totally bypass RFCOMM implementation?

Comment: I am okay with a downvote, but, more positively, the user could also have commented/answered that question. That could have lead to some fruitful thinking.

Comment: I don't think you should lose sleep over a single downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intent is to communicate with smartphones, forget about that. Just use rfcomm as l2cap sockets are forbidden/locked down most of the time.

Otherwise, if you control the machines (which are not smartphones) do whatever you feel is best.

Even if you find some -older- smartphones accepting L2CAP sockets, it is definitely not a good strategy to rely on "luck" basically.

Comment: Thanks Amy. So I will use rfcomm for a broader audience.